# Hover doesn't work as expected with classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to to translate each of these elements with the same class .. for example if I hover one of these classes I want just the class hovered to be translated not all of them .. Here is my code :

```
<div class="latestNewsHeadLines">

 <ul>

   <li class="headlineCl">text1</li>
   <li class="headlineCl">text2</li>
   <li class="headlineCl">text3</li>       
   <li class="headlineCl">text4</li>    

 </ul>

</div>
```

jQuery Code :

```
 $(".headlineCl").hover(function(){

    var Length = $(this).width();
    var transRight = -(Length -245) ;


    $(".headlineCl a").css({'right':transRight+"px"})


});
```

Thank you!

Comment: use `this` context

Comment: There is no <a> tag under class="headlineCl" in HTML

Comment: hahah yes .. i made a mistake whrn typing but it should to be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your html actually has an `a` tag unlike the provided html:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKqrVA)

```
 $(".headlineCl").hover(function(){
    var Length = $(this).width();
    var transRight = -(Length -245) ;
    // `this` refers to the selector to which 
    // your hover function is attached 
    $(this).find('a').css({'right':transRight+"px"})
});
```

Otherwise, you can use:

```
$(".headlineCl").hover(function(){
    var Length = $(this).width();
    var transRight = -(Length -245) ;
    // `this` refers to the selector to which 
    // your hover function is attached
    $(this).css({'right':transRight+"px"})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".headlineCl").hover(function(){

    var Length = $(this).width();
    var transRight = -(Length -245) ;
  
    $("a").css('color','black')//put color black on all anchor element(remove red color)
    $("a",this).css('color','red')// use this context to tell the hovered element. this will put color red to hovered element


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="latestNewsHeadLines">

 <ul>

   <li class="headlineCl"><a>text1</a></li>
   <li class="headlineCl"><a>text2</a></li>
   <li class="headlineCl"><a>text3</a></li>       
   <li class="headlineCl"><a>text4</a></li>    

 </ul>

</div>
```

1. Use `this` context to tell the element being hovered